# Javascript regex for string with a number in it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I'm currently working within an AngularJS directive and in the template I'm attempting to check if a an instance variable of the Controller is a certain type of string.

Specifically, this string can be anything at all so long as it has an 8-digit number in it.
Passing Examples: "gdbfgihfb 88827367 dfgfdg", "12345678", ".12345678"
The number has to be a solid string of 8 numbers with nothing in between.

I've tried this:

```
$ctrl.var == /[0-9]{8}/
```

But it doesn't work for some reason.  How do I construct a regex in order to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Add "from start to end" `/^[0-9]{8}$/`. `/^\d{8}$/` looks good too.

Comment: Why it cannot work? Have some logs?

Comment: Provide more code pls. The regex seems fine.

Comment: I think you need this: `/.*\d{8}.*/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is fine but the comparison is wrong. You want

```
/\d{8}/.test($ctrl.var)
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

```js
let tests = ["gdbfgihfb 88827367 dfgfdg", "12345678", ".12345678", "nope, no numbers here"],
    rx = /\d{8}/;

tests.map(str => document.write(`<pre>"${str}": ${rx.test(str)}</pre>`))
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
var first = "gdbfgihfb 88827367 dfgfdg";
var second = "12345678";
var third = ".12345678";

var reg = new RegExp('[0-9]{8}');

console.log(first.match(reg));
console.log(second.match(reg));
console.log(third.match(reg));
```

Output:

```
[ '88827367', index: 10, input: 'gdbfgihfb 88827367 dfgfdg' ]
[ '12345678', index: 0, input: '12345678' ]
[ '12345678', index: 1, input: '.12345678' ]
```